# The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version

Tags: python

I am running a python script with the following code:

```
def populate_indicators(self, dataframe: DataFrame, metadata: dict) -> DataFrame:
        tik = time.perf_counter()
        #only 1 time for populates, dont work backtesting
        btc_info_pair = "BTC/USDT"
        if metadata['pair'] in btc_info_pair:
            btc_info_tfx = self.info_tf_btc_indicators(dataframe, metadata)
            #logger.info(f"BTC SSL 1 time for pairs, Trend  {self.custom_trendBTC_info['trend']}")
            
        dataframe['btctrend'] = self.custom_trendBTC_info['trend']
```

However I am getting the following warning because of the last line of code:

" FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning."

Please help me to fix the warning.

I tried the following code too:

```
dataframe['btctrend'] = pd.concat(dataframe['btctrend'], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

However, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Reading one column creates pandas.series and if it is empty then this warning comes up.
You can give column type as below.

`dataframe['btctrend'] = self.custom_trendBTC_info['trend'].astype(float)`

Comment: Unfortunately, that suggestion didn't work. I am still getting the warning msg:                                              
                                                                          
"FutureWarning: The default dtype for empty Series will be 'object' instead of 'float64' in a future version. Specify a dtype explicitly to silence this warning.
  dataframe['btctrend'] = Index(self.custom_trendBTC_info['trend'], dtype= "object")